# Which service could I use to train my networks?

Tags: training, computer-vision, gan

My laptop's Intel i7 3630QM 2.4GHZ, 8Gb RAM and GXForce 670M are clearly not sufficient...

By reading some papers, I've written an SRGAN with Python Keras. At runtime there is no error but training only 2 images (324*324) with 1 epoch, batch size of 2 lasts too much...perhaps more than 1 hour of training...

Which service could I use to train my deep neural networks, see the console outputs, eventually see plots, and download the trained model?
Are there such paid services? Free services?

The idea would be that I query the compute server from my laptop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use **google colab** which is free. It proposes notebooks usage, which are hosted on a server with good GPUs for machine and deep learning. You can write python code and train your models in real-time.

https://colab.research.google.com/

However, if you are inactive for a medium period, the platform will eject you. So if you plan to train really big models durings days and weeks, you should use cloud plateforms like AWS or Google Cloud. Note that these plateforms can quickly become expensive (but you often get some free credit when you register).

Answer (score 2):

You can use AWS EC2, or the GCP Compute Engine, or the GCP Machine Learning Engine. You pay based on how many CPU/GPUs you employ and on training times.

Comment: This is the right answer, but I would also add [colab](https://colab.research.google.com/) for a less useful but free version for experimentation